# iTextSharp Mixed Alignments in Same Object

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to have a function that returns one object, with this object containing two paragraph with different alignments. This is easy to do manually by making them separate paragraphs and adding them to the pdf one at a time, but I would like my function to return it as a whole object to be added to a pdf. Is this possible? As an example of what I want:

```
 someTextHere


                                                                      someMoreTextHere
```

But as one object which I can then add to a pdf.

Comment: How about returning a collection of objects to add using `foreach`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a small standalone iText 7 example that creates the following output:

[image]

Th PDF file shown in the screen shot was created like this:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    Div div = new Div()
        .add(new Paragraph("Left").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT))
        .add(new Paragraph("Right").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT))
        .setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.GRAY)
        .setWidth(200);
    document.add(div);
    document.close();
}
```

As you can see, I created a `Div` element (similar to a `<div>` tag in HTML) to which I added two `Paragraph` objects with a different text alignment. That seems to be exactly what you need.

I am not a C# developer, hence I provide the code in Java. However, if you're proficient in C#, you shouldn't have any problem porting it from Java to C# (it's just a matter of changing lowercases into uppercases, such as changing `add()` into `Add()`).

Note that this is iText 7 code; if you're still using iText 5, you should consider upgrading to the latest iText version since iText 5 has gone into maintenance mode a while ago. Maintenance mode means that development on that version has stopped; it's no longer supported for users who aren't a customer.